# How is this error possible: Unrecognized Selected (screenFontWithRenderingMode) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This one doesn't make any sense to me.  My app crashes with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType screenFontWithRenderingMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x209bb200'
```

This is an iOS app. From what I can see, screenFontWithRenderingMode is an NSFont method for Mac OS X, not iOS.  So how can this error even be occurring?

I am building the app with the newly released Xcode 5.  The app will support iOS version 6.1 and 7.0 (and higher).  This error ONLY occurs when running the app on a 6.1 device (and simulator).

EDIT:

I wasn't able to produce the crash log by running the app in debug mode. By creating an Ad Hoc build I was able to load the app, run it, crash, and retrieve the crash log:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3220a29e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a06e97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3220de02 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 166
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3220c52c ___forwarding___ + 388
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32163f64 __forwarding_prep_0___ + 20
5   UIFoundation                    0x37da15c8 +[NSStringDrawingTextStorage _fastDrawString:attributes:length:inRect:graphicsContext:baselineRendering:usesFontLeading:usesScreenFont:typesetterBehavior:paragraphStyle:lineBreakMode:boundingRect:padding:scrollable:baselineOffset:] + 344
6   UIFoundation                    0x37da0184 -[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) _doBoundingRectWithSize:options:context:baselineOffset:] + 676
7   UIFoundation                    0x37d9fc8c -[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:context:] + 2492
```

I was able to track down the offending line:

```
CGRect rect = [[MLFeedCell attributedBodyForItem:item].attributedString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(labelWidth, 10000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with this call.

Comment: It would be helpful to show folks the call stack and tell us where the exception actually originated from.

Comment: iOS is a derivative of OS X, it seems likely that iOS uses some OS X-only methods internally (private API, not available for developers).

Comment: What is the implementation of MLFeedCell?

Comment: MLFeedCell contains various text and image elements, but basically this line of code is retrieving the text field which happens to be an NSAttributedString, and attempts the correct height based on how much text it contains.

Comment: You may be running into an ARC issue. Try: `MLFeedCell *cell = [MLFeedCell attributedBodyForItem:item]; CGRect rect = [cell.attributedString boundingRectWithSize:...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to use:

```
[NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:]
```

That method was added in IOS 7.0 in the **NSStringDrawing.h** category.

source:

- [IOS7 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/)

Comment: This is not the case for me. I'm getting the same error and I'm calling the boundingRectWithSize from a NSAttributedString.